# Apply block of list condition in dataframe

Tags: r, data-science, data-wrangling

I am trying to apply some new conditions to the existing data frame (as below). I could not use `ifelse` because the logic is like this:

1. If count<=3: keep as it is
2. If count>3 :

   - If Code != "OFF15", c = "OK10" else c = "OFF15"
3. If count > 3 and code is NA: Code= "OK10"

I could not generate the third condition when using ifelse

```
Code = c("OFF15","OFF5",NA,"OFF5",NA)
count= c(3,4,4,2,1)
x= data.frame(Code,count)
```

I could not use ifelse as there is nested list for that. My expected will be:

```
Code    Count
OFF15     3
OK10      2
OK10      3
OFF5      2
NA        1
```

Comment: May I ask: Is c the same as count?

Comment: (1) I think your expected output doesn't match your input. (2) Your question is confusing since you are using different names in your data and your question.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry my bad. Updated

Comment: what is your desired output if count is ==3?

Comment: if it is equal it will be as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use nested `ifelse`s (it is still borderline OK with just one level of nesting, otherwise `case_when` is almost imperative).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Code = ifelse(count<=3, Code, ifelse(!Code %in% "OFF15", "OK10", "OFF15"))
```

Comment: in your code if count 4 and code is original = NA it will not generate the correct result

Comment: Try again with the edited code. I substituted `%in%`, which evaluates NA %in% TRUE to FALSE, for '=='

Comment: I also suggest you include these extreme cases in the actual data, so that we can test the answer in a proper reproducible example.

Comment: I have try to apply your code into the actual data, so far it has not generated any problems. Thank you so much for helping

Comment: I did not know that the R treats NA as a TRUE, thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help. Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Code = case_when(count < 3 ~ Code,
                          count > 3 & Code != "OFF15" ~ "OK10",
                          TRUE ~ "OFF15"))
```

This returns

```r
   Code count
1 OFF15     3
2  OK10     4
3 OFF15     3
4  OFF5     2
5  <NA>     1
```

Note: I named the data.frame `df` instead of `x`.

Comment: Do you mind if i ask in case if the count >3 but initial code is NA the value return as OFF 15 instead of LARGE 10. How could we modify it

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I was on holydays. Climbed the Zugspitze. ⛰️

Answer (score 0):

Using `fcase` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, Code := fcase(count < 3, Code, count > 3 & Code != "OFF15", 
        "OK10", default = "OFF15")]
 x
    Code count
1: OFF15     3
2:  OK10     4
3: OFF15     4
4:  OFF5     2
5:  <NA>     1
```